# How to force "submit for review" instead of "update" for custom post types in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am creating a business directory website, using Wordpress and ACF. I have a custom post type: firms.

For each firm, I will create a user (author or contributor) and they will be able to create and edit Firms (Custom Post Type).

However, I don't want the firms to be able to update these posts freely. Whenever they want to create a new firm, or edit a published firm of their owns, they should see "Submit for review".

When the user role is set to contributor, they can add new firm (with "Submit for review" button) but they cannot edit their firms later.

When the user role is set to author, they can edit and update a firm without submitting for review.

Do you know how can I solve this issue?